# Check if there are 3 same characters in a row in the string

Tags: assembly, nasm

My code doesn't work. 
The problem is with lea (line 6). NetBeansIDE says "invalid combination of opcode and operands". 
Are there any workarounds to get this working?
Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
global _main
section .data
text: db "fdkvemDFderft", 0

section .text
_main:
    lea si, text
no:
    lodsb
    or al,al
    jz exit
    cmp al,[si]
    jnz no
    cmp al,[si+1]
    jnz no
    ;code
exit: 
    ;code

    mov eax, 4C00h
    ret
```

.

```
-f win32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
lea si, [text]
```

lea loads the address resulting from the addressing mode address calculation. therefore, we express label as address with this.

many would probably just

```
mov si, text
```

Comment: Thanks. However it still doesn't work. Though now it compiles without problems. 
When I write 'mov si, text' it gives me "coff format does not support non-32-bit relocations"

Comment: well, that another problem. don't generate COFF format - which makes very little sense, seen that you terminate program with an MS/DOS function call (which should load, btw, 4c00H into AX). you probably want to generate a COM file which is a plain binary image ORGed to 0100H. COFF was used with Unix mostly, before ELF more or less replaced it.

Comment: actually, you don't teminate  - you only start setting up termination but don't complete it. though  4c00 in AX may be also a way to terminate windows program, i don't know anything about windows.